# A note from your moderator team

Tags: discussion

Some of you may have noticed that Jolenealaska currently doesn't have a diamond. Unfortunately, she has some stressful ongoing health issues that are consuming much of her time and energy, so she's had to step away for the moment. At this point we can't say exactly how long it'll be, but we wish her a speedy recovery, and hope to have her back on the team when she's ready.

In the meantime, she'll surely be around the site as much as she's able, sharing her cooking knowledge and enthusiasm.

Comment: Ow, that's very saddening. I'm very sorry to hear that, hope she gets well ASAP.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Yes, I'm fine; and yes, I'll be back :)

Answer (score 8):

Stack Exchange and Seasoned Advice have been very supportive during a difficult yet very interesting time of my life. Some individuals especially - You Know Who You Are. Thank you.

I have had and continue to have some pretty significant health issues, including Multiple Sclerosis and a right ankle that has now broken twice for no good or completely understood reason. Those kinds of health challenges are taking up a lot of my energy right now, and soon I will be traveling to Seattle for an exhaustive orthopedic, endocrine and neurologic workup. Until then, no news is good news. I have nothing new to report on my physical health.

My mental health is a whole different ball of wax. As some of you know, for about 2 months I have been in a completely different reality than the one most of you probably share. To put it in a different (and totally non-clinical) way, I have been crazier than the proverbial rat in a tin sh*thouse.

Since I am trying to become a better writer and have few actual responsibilities, this little trip down the rabbit hole has been a positive experience for the most part. Since SCOTUS has finally legalized gay marriage everywhere in the US, marijuana is legal in the State of Alaska, and certain people don't want to hear my opinions about our (ahem) president, I have been needing a new pet cause. I think I have found it.

Mental illness of all types still carries with it a huge stigma, even among people who consider themselves to be quite enlightened and progressive about most difficult-to-discuss things. That's a shame. That stigma often keeps people with mental illness from getting the help they need, leading to tragic results for them and for society as a whole. In the interest of stimulating a dialog, I have created a chat room open to anyone who would like to discuss the issue, their personal dealings with it, or my experiences. It may move to a more appropriate site, but for now, it's [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71951/after-the-rabbit-hole). Come chat with me if you'd like. It is my intention to be very open and transparent about most of what has happened and ongoing events.

I am now nearly as close to sane as I ever am, and I will be one of your moderators again soon, probably right after my trip to Seattle. Until then, too much of my energy is wrapped up in that. Still, I will be in and out, but I will be keeping an eye on Seasoned Advice and chat.

Thanks again, guys.

Comment: Glad to hear you're doing better and finding ways to deal with it all. On the last bit, returning to a mod role, I just want to say we'll be happy to have you back when you're ready but don't pressure yourself - it's totally fine if you need to stay flexible about your plans and take care of yourself.

Comment: *Mental illness of all types still carries with it a huge stigma* You writing openly about it helps reduce that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm back, pleased to once again be a part of your moderation team. I'm a bit rusty, but it won't take me long to get back to unapologetically making unpopular decisions.

Don't be shy if you'd like to bring up the issues that kept me away for a few months. I'll be in the Frying Pan nearly as often as not, just like I used to be. I've grown accustomed to this place :D